# Scrolling with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am having some trouble scrolling down to the end of the second web page. The first scroll works fine, the second won't run.

This issue seems to be happening on line 33 and 34

Please see lines of code below:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

def main():
    n = 1
    # LMS -> PSYC1101 -> Quiz
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")
    driver.get("https://lms.uwa.edu.au/webapps/portal/execute/tabs/tabAction?tab_tab_group_id=_1_1")
    window_before = driver.window_handles[0]
    username = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"login-user"))).send_keys("username")
    password = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"login-pass"))).send_keys("password")
    login = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"form_button_0"))).click()
    time.sleep(10)
    units = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[4]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a/span"))).click()
    psych = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/ul/li[4]/a"))).click()
    page = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("html")
    page.send_keys(Keys.END)
    time.sleep(1)
    quizzes = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/nav/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[22]/a/span"))).click()

    # Quiz One -> Begin -> Scroll -> Continue -> Sumbit -> Submit2 -> View Results
    quizOne = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/div[1]/h3/a/span"))).click()
    time.sleep(1)
    begin = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[17]/button"))).click()

    window_after = driver.window_handles[0]
    driver.switch_to.window(window_after)

    page = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("html")
    page.send_keys(Keys.END)
    #driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    Continue = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div/div/main/div[5]/button[1]"))).click()
    submit = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div/header/div/div/button[2]"))).click()
    submit2 =  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div/ic-modal[2]/ic-modal-main/div[2]/button[2]"))).click()       
    viewResults = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div/ic-modal[3]/ic-modal-main/div/button"))).click()


main()
```

Comment: Where do you want to scroll?

Comment: Does this second page open in a new tab?

Comment: I am trying to scroll down to the bottom of the page so that I can click on the "continue" button. No the second website does not open in a new tab, it just takes you to a new website within the same tab